# JS: difference between document.evaluate(".//html"... and document.evaluate("//html"...?

Tags: javascript, document.evaluate

Does dot (`.`) matters in `document.evaluate`? I tested and it does not seem to do anything

mozilla tutorials use it in examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate

Answer (score 1):

The dot refers to the currently selected node within the element tree that you are on.

If you look at the function definition this is shown here

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
 xpathExpression, 
 *contextNode*, 
 namespaceResolver, 
 resultType, 
 result
);
```

It is common to pass in the document as the context object. If you also note the following line from the website you linked

> In this example, the "." is important to indicate that the querying should start from the context node

All of this of course originates from XPath.

Perhaps you would like to look at query selector instead if you don't wish to use xpath : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Comment: oh, I didn't see that part, but still have question about it: 
`the query would start from the root node (html)`
is that above `document` or inside it? I mean If my `contextNode` is `document` - should I write dot `.` or not?

Comment: The dot in `.//html` means you be performing your xpaths from the context you pass in, ie the document node, whilst `//html` will search for any child of the root node and completely ignore the context you passed in.

Comment: I mean - what is the `root node` ? parent of `document` or the `document` ?

Comment: If you've never used XPath before, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) may help you.
Sidenote; I'm not a fan of w3schools, but the information there is correct.

Comment: I have tons of document.evaluate() in my code, but now I'm just wondering what the `root node` will be if I don't use the dot `.`

Comment: The dot `.` will evaluate to whatever the second argument for your evaluate() call is, ie `document.evaluate("xpath", CONTEXT_NODE, ...)`

Comment: I know that already, I want to know what it will evaluate to if there is NO DOT `.` , what is the root node. `document` element or ...?